# preventing scroll of md-dialog, which is the parent of md-automplete when md-automplete is opened

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

[image]
I have an md-automplete on the md-dialog of the angular material(1.1.6), on opening md-automplete if we try to scroll through the modal then it allows doing so and leaving the autocomplete menu as open.
i want it to not allow the scroll through the modal till the time autocomplete is open.
once closed,it can allow to scroll the modal-dialog as well.

I have created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mohanmanis/pen/bLMjaK?editors=1010)

Html looks like the following:

```html
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="autocompletedemoInsideDialog" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <p>
      Click the button below to open the dialog with an autocomplete.
    </p>

    <md-button ng-click="ctrl.openDialog($event)" class="md-raised">Open Dialog</md-button>
  </md-content>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dialog.tmpl.html"><md-dialog aria-label="Autocomplete Dialog Example" style="overflow-y:auto">

  <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h2>Autocomplete Dialog Example</h2>
  Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>

  <md-dialog-content ng-cloak>
    <div class="md-dialog-content">
      <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
        <p>Use <code>md-autocomplete</code> to search for matches from local or remote data sources.</p>
        <md-autocomplete
            md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
            md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
            md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
            md-item-text="item.display"
            md-min-length="0"
            placeholder="What is your favorite US state?"
            md-autofocus="">
          <md-item-template>
            <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.display}}</span>
          </md-item-template>
          <md-not-found>
            No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
          </md-not-found>
        </md-autocomplete>
      </form>
    </div>
  </md-dialog-content>

  <md-dialog-actions>
    <md-button aria-label="Finished" ng-click="ctrl.finish($event)">Finished</md-button>
  </md-dialog-actions>
</md-dialog>
</script></div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what the desired and undesired behaviour is. When I open the dialog in your example, the parent container does not scroll, only the US-State select.

Comment: after opening the dialog scroll through the list of state and try to scroll the dialog then you will see that dropdown is open and still you are able to scroll through the dialog.

Comment: This is how it looks like when I am testing: https://thumbs.gfycat.com/FixedLeftDonkey-size_restricted.gif

Comment: Please have a look on this :: https://media.giphy.com/media/g4IN2m1Lju5wiZGc5P/giphy.gif